# Why Printing "OK" changes output?

Tags: c++

Please have a look at this code

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ami[100000], tumi[100000];
    scanf("%s ", ami);
    scanf("%s ", tumi);
//************ This is the Problem***********
   cout << "OK" << endl;
//*******************************************
    int l1 = strlen(ami);
    int l2 = strlen(tumi);
    int fwd[l1+1];
    int rev[l1+1];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < l1;i++)
    {
        if(j < l2 && ami[i] == tumi[j])
        {
            j++;
            fwd[i]++;
        }
        if(i!=0)
        fwd[i] += fwd[i-1];
    }
    j = l2- 1;
    for(int i = l1-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(j >= 0 && ami[i] == tumi[j] )
        {
            j--;
            rev[i]++;
        }
        if(i!= l1-1)
        rev[i]+=rev[i+1];
    }
    long long int Q, HUDAI;
    scanf("%lld %lld", &Q, &HUDAI);

    for(int i = 0; i < Q; i++)
    {
        long long int x, y;
        scanf("%lld %lld", &x, &y);
        if(fwd[x-1]+rev[y+1] >= l2) cout << "YES" << endl;
        else cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I run this program for following input

```
abcabcxy
ax
2 2
2 6
6 7
```

In this code if I run the same code several times (5-7 times) it shows different output..
Sometimes   "OK YES NO" sometimes "OK YES YES"..
But If I comment the "cout << "OK" << endl;" line it always shows "YES YES" 
Can any one say me why this is happening ?
How to get rid of this ?

Comment: It means your code has undefined behavior.  Somewhere you are doing something illegal, most likely you are agoing out of the bounds of an array.  Use your debugger to step through the code and make sure all your array accesses are legal.

Comment: This looks fishy `if (ami[i] == tumi[j] && j < l2)`. Do the check *before* indexing.

Comment: First guess `int fwd[l1]` -> `int fwd[l1 + 1]`, you need room for the NUL terminator

Comment: I have done this ( fwd[l1+1] ) still same problem.

Comment: `int fwd[l1+1];` is a variable length array (VLA). VLAs are not part of c++ (unless your compiler adds support as an extension).

Comment: @AshiqurRahman In this line `rev[j]++;`, `j` becomes negative at some point. Just like @NathanOliver sugested in his comment.

Comment: You tagged the question with C++ but you don't use the tools that come with C++. Use `std::string`, `std::array` and `std::vector` and you will find the problem.

Comment: Do you really need `ami` and `tumi` to be 100k buffers? That could be causing stack overflow (note: no capital S and O).

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? I mean what are its functional requirements?

Comment: thanks @ThomasSablik. I have fixed that. But it still shows different output at different time.

Comment: "*In this code if I run the same code several times (5-7 times) it shows different output.*" are you saying that you get different output when running with the same *input*?

Comment: YES @JohnFilleau

Comment: You still haven't answered what this code is supposed to do. What are its functional requirements?

Comment: Here I always get `NO NO`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/XKZ12RpAvJkmbXKr What is the correct output?

Comment: There is even more out of bounds access but you've hidden it. You created two arrays with `char ami[100000], tumi[100000];`. You didn't initialize them. You read 8 and 2 chars. But you access the uninitialized element `tumi[2]`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/bxnX1elI1OMwflHn

Comment: First please consider CONST as array size. second make sure check range for x,y. Third initialize the values of those arrays. You are just assuming they are going to be filled with 0.

Comment: But here different output [https://wandbox.org/permlink/oGbgVVuZz6DGiSiD]. I can't find any difference between this two code. @ThomasSablik

Comment: Please stop using C strings, C arrays, non-standard extensions. Use STL containers and strings. I already found 2 out of bounds errors and there are probably even more. I'm not able to fix the second error because you didn't describe what the code should do.

Comment: Fourth, why are you using long long int if its just range [1, 100000]. Please fix all these bad practices and then check

Comment: Don't cross the streams.  When using `scanf`, use `printf` (or puts).  When using `cout`, use `cin`.  This will help remove some unintended defects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some cases of out of bounds errors. I removed the C strings, C arrays and non-standard features and added some bound checks and moved one bound check. Now your code outputs `NO NO` and I didn't find any undefined behavior:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::string ami, tumi;
  std::cin >> ami >> tumi;
  //************ This is the Problem***********
  std::cout << "OK\n";
  //*******************************************
  const int l1 = ami.length();
  const int l2 = tumi.length();
  std::vector<int> fwd(l1 + 1);
  std::vector<int> rev(l1 + 1);
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < l1; ++i) {
    if (static_cast<std::size_t>(j) < tumi.length() &&
        ami.at(i) == tumi.at(j) && j < l2) {
      ++j;
      ++fwd[i];
    }
    if (i != 0) fwd.at(i) += fwd.at(i - 1);
  }
  for (int i = l1 - 1, j = l2 - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (j >= 0 && ami.at(i) == tumi.at(j)) {
      --j;
      ++rev.at(i);
    }
    if (i != l1 - 1) rev.at(i) += rev.at(i + 1);
  }
  long long int Q, HUDAI;
  std::cin >> Q >> HUDAI;

  for (int i = 0; i < Q; ++i) {
    long long int x, y;
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    if (fwd.at(x - 1) + rev.at(y + 1) >= l2)
      std::cout << "YES\n";
    else
      std::cout << "NO\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```